# Friendly URL and Content Deployment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, wcm

SharePoint 2013 has introduced Friendly URLs and is implemented using Managed Meta Data Service. The Content Deployment will complain **Metadata Navigation is not supported Deactivate Metadata Navigation**

We need to have the architecture like Source Farm where content authors create content. And using Content Deployment or Quick deploy to publish the content in the target farm with the Friendly URL's

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because the terms won't be the same accross farms (guid wise) unless you first restore a backup from source to production environment (but what about future changes...). Setting up a cross farms Shared Services might help I think but not sure the lovely content deployment jobs will see this architecture.

Answer (score 1):

What about XPS? Cross Site Publishing now is the preferred way to publish content in these kinds of scenarios.

Everything in Waldek blog is gold for this topic: [blog.mastykarz.nl](http://blog.mastykarz.nl)

Answer (score 0):

This is how SharePoint 2013 works. Nothing you can do about it.

What you can do is to have your catalogs/content in a remote farm and leverage that through federated search.